# Не отображаются выбранные категории на django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

я учусь делать сайты на django, пока что простенькие. Нужно чтобы  категория выбранного аккаунта отображалась через тег p, а все остальные через a. По итогу все категории отображаются как ссылки [Как должно выглядеть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0N9E.png)
[Как по итогу отображается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbQW0.png)

Части кода

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_category(filter=None):
    if not filter:
        return Category.objects.all()
    else:
        return Category.objects.filter(slug_fields=filter)

@register.simple_tag(name="hypixel_accaunts")
def get_accaunt():
    return hypixel.objects.all()


@register.inclusion_tag('product/hyp_cats.html')
def show_category(sort=None, cat_selected=0):
    if not sort:
        category = Category.objects.all()
    else:
        category = Category.objects.order_by(sort)
    return {'category': category, 'cat_selected' : cat_selected}
```

Из hyp_cats.html

```
{% for c in category %}
    {% if c.slug_fields  == cat_selected %}
        <p>{{ c.name }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }} </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Из основного шаблона

```
    {% get_category as get_cats %}
    {% if cat_selected == 0 %}
        <p>Все аккаунты</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'hype' %}">Все аккаунты</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% show_category '-name' cat_selected %}
    <br>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
```

из views.py

```
def show_acc(request, acc_id):
    accaunt = get_object_or_404(hypixel, nickname=acc_id)
    contex = {
        'accaunt': accaunt,
        'cat_selected' : accaunt.cat,
    }
    return render(request,'product/hype_accaunt.html', context=contex)
```

из models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    slug_fields = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cats', kwargs ={'cat_id' : self.slug_fields})
```

Если нужны будут еще части кода, то пишите

Суть сайта в отображении аккаунтов из баз данных, у каждого из аккаунтов есть категории, категория аккаунта зависит от его доната. При заходе на страницу выбранного аккаунта отображаются его характеристики, слева вверху отображаются меню со всеми  категории которые возможны, они выполнены как ссылки, однако если допустим выбран аккаунт у которого категория 'VIP', в этом меню категория 'VIP' будет отображаться через тег p, а не через a как другие.